# Write a function that has the same default values as a constructor

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, generics, kotlin-js

**Abstract problem**:

Consider the following:

```
data class Data(val i: Int, val s: String = "")

fun <A1, A2, D> make(ctor: KFunction2<A1, A2, D>, sideEffect: (D) -> D) =
    { a1: A1, a2: A2 -> sideEffect(ctor(a1, a2)) }

val makeData = make(::Data) {
    it.also { println("Side effect: i=${it.i}, s=${it.s}") }
}
```

I can call makeData with all of the constructor arguments to obtain
an instance of `Data` and also call some side-effect. However, I
cannot omit parameters and use the constructor's default values instead:

```
val d1 = makeData(42, "hi")
val d2 = makeData2(42) // Error: No value passed for parameter 'p2'
```

How can I rewrite the generic `make` such that its output is a function with default values?

**What I'm trying to achieve**:

With Kotlin React, I declare properties like so:

```
external interface VideoListProps: RProps { var videos: List<Video> }
```

To use the component within render(), I can write:

```
child(VideoList::class) { attrs.videos = unwatchedVideos }
```

I don't like this for three reasons: (a) using a component is much more verbose than compared to TypeScript/TSX,
(b) properties need to be declared as var while they should be read-only (val), (c) there is no enforcement that a member is actually declared; `props.videos` may end up as `null` at runtime even though the Props interface does not declare it as nullable.

The tutorial for Kotlin React suggests to use lambdas with receivers like so:

```
fun RBuilder.videoList(handler: VideoListProps.() -> Unit): ReactElement {
    return child(VideoList::class) {
        this.attrs(handler)
    }
}
```

Now I can use the component like so:

```
videoList { videos = unwatchedVideos }
```

While the calling site now looks much more concise, I now have to copy/paste and adapt the lambda snippet for each and every component I write. This is much more verbose than in TypeScript, where I don't need this construct. Moreover, the videoList lambda has no access to other members of the RBuilder as `this` now points to RProps. So if I need to define a React `key`, I'm at a loss and need to use the child(...) syntax from before. And lastly, the problem (c) from above still exists.

To make this better, I wrote the following helper constructs:

```
fun <P : RProps, A1> RBuilder.childWithProps(
    klass: KClass<out Component<P, *>>,
    ctor: KFunction1<A1, P>
) =
    { a1: A1, handler: RHandler<P> -> child(klass.rClass, ctor(a1), handler) }

fun <P : RProps, A1, A2> RBuilder.childWithProps(
    klass: KClass<out Component<P, *>>,
    ctor: KFunction2<A1, A2, P>
) =
    { a1: A1, a2: A2, handler: RHandler<P> -> child(klass.rClass, ctor(a1, a2), handler) }

// more for KFunction3, KFunction4, ... up to a reasonable amount of members, e.g. 16
```

I admit this is also kind of ugly, but I need to write this once only. Now I can declare props like this (note the val instead of var):

```
data class VideoListProps(val videos: List<Videos>) : RProps
```

The additional code for each component is now much more concise:

```
val RBuilder.videoList get() = childWithProps(VideoList::class, ::VideoListProps)
```

And use it like this:

```
videoList(watchedVideos) { /* you can set React key or children here if needed */ }
```

Kotlin now marks it as an error if I forget to set all properties.
Everything now looks concise, I write even slightly less code than in TypeScript/TSX. The only remaining problem is that now I always have to pass all members, since any default values of the data constructor will still be madatory in the wrapper. **This is the actual question.**

Comment: Why don't you just take a constucted `D` as input?

Comment: Because I'd like to make the use of it as simple as possible. `sideEffect(Data1(a, b))` is more complicated than `makeData1(a, b)`.

Comment: I rewrote the question to make clear what I'm trying to achieve.